# What does the SQueryL tilde operator do?

Tags: scala, squeryl

I was reading the SQueryL [documentation](http://squeryl.org/inserts-updates-delete.html) on updating and I saw:

```
update(songs)(s =>
  where(s.title === "Watermelon Man")
  set(s.title := "The Watermelon Man",
      s.year  := s.year.~ + 1)
)
```

I had a hard time finding the ~ method from the SQueryL source code and the linked documentation obviously doesn't tell me what it does either. Does anyone care to explain?

Comment: The documentation seems incomplete... perhaps try their mailing list?

Comment: I've asked the discussion group as the docs are broken and I'm curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall reading about the tilde operator not too long ago on the [Schema Definition Page](http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html). 
It is about disambiguating between a primitive and a custom type, although (as I am just beginning to learn Scala) it still sounds a bit vague to me ;). To quote a little piece

> ...
>
> important : in PrimitiveTypes mode there can be ambiguities between numeric operators
>
> When using org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode, the compiler will treat an expression like the 
>   one in the next example as a Boolean. The .~ function is needed to tell the compiler that the 
>   left side is a node of TypedExpressionNode[Int] which will cause the whole expression to be a
>   LogicalBoolean which is what the where clause takes :
>
> ...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah ok. So it seems that the ~ op comes from NumericalExpression, which you get from some magical implicit conversion from PrimitiveTypeMode after typing ~. The only reason you need it is because due to the magical nature of implicits, you never know for sure what any arithmetic/logical ops will resolve to. Using 'plus' or '~' ensures you get the right type.